# Find a biholomorphic map

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently stuck on how to find a biholomorphic map between two subset $A,B\subset \mathbb{C}$. Given by:

$$ A:= \left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\ \big| \ |z|<1 \right\} \\
   B:= \left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\ \middle| \ \Im(z) \ge (\Re(z))^2\right\} $$

It seems that the circles in $A$ must be mapped onto the parabolas.

But I don't see how to do it!

Answer (score 2):

Use the map $w=z^2$ to map the vertical line $\text{Re}(z)=1$ to the parabola with vertex at $z=1$ whose axis of symmetry is the $x$-axis. The map can then be composed with a usual (birational) map between a circle and a line.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary circe of $A$ has equation $x^2+y^2=1$. If you use the transformation $x=\frac{2X}{Y+1}$ and $y=\frac{Y-1}{Y+1}$ then the equation of the circle will be transformed into the equation of the parabola $Y=X^2$. Now check that this is given by a holomorphic map.

Comment: Ok, gonna check that ...

Comment: Hmm, I don't really see how to get the holomorphic map from this

Comment: @mjb4, you are right, the approach using projective maps does not work.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Since I recently came across this problem and got the answer here, here are the details of the answer of @user72694.

One map that maps the line $Im(z) = 0$ to $Re(z) = 1$ is $\varphi : z\mapsto iz+1$. Since this also maps the standard parabola to the parabola given by @user72694, this yields a biholomorphism $z\mapsto \varphi^{-1}(\varphi(z)^2) = 2z +iz^2$ between the upper half plane and the "parabola domain".

I choose the biholomorphism between the upper half plane and the parabola domain to be $\psi(z) = \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ (with inverse $z\mapsto \frac{iz-i}{-z+1}$). Then the biholomorphism $A\to B$ comes out as $z\mapsto \frac{z^2-2iz -i}{iz^2 + 2z -1}$.

Comment: thx for the answer, but right know I can't really check if it is right! Forgot most of the stuff in that subject.